# How to log to file and to console

Tags: logs, console

I know that I can log to file by adding

```
> log.txt
```

to the end of a command but how can I log to file AND to console?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

try using `tee`?

```
| tee log.txt
```

instead of

```
> log.txt
```

Answer (score 16):

There are various ways by which you can make log. But the first and the foremost thing is what actually you want to put in your log. You can do that in various ways:

1. Tee command splits the output of a command so that it can be seen on the display and also be saved in  a file.

   ```
   command | tee log.txt
   ```

   The above command will display the output to terminal as well as it will redirect the output to the file `log.txt`.
2. The script command makes a typescript(copy) of everything printed on your terminal:

   ```
   script -a log.txt
   ```

Answer (score 6):

Use the [`tee` command](http://man.cx/tee):

```
some_command | tee log.txt
```